# How to add a property to an object that is in a ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I would like to send to a template a new property in a model that is in a ManyToManyField

I have this loop in one of my models with ManyToManyField:

```
for bar in foo.bars.all():
   #This property 'allow_something' doesn't exist in model, I just need it in this situation
   bar.allow_something = True
```

In the same code, if I try this everything goes as expected:

```
#It will print "True"
print(bar.allow_something)
```

But when I call the new property in the template, it doesn't work. This is the code in my HTML template:

```
{% for bar in foo.bars.all %}
   {{ bar.allow_something }} <-- nothing happens here. It should display "True"
{% endfor %}
```

Please, can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: well if it does not exists in the model, then it is not persistent, hence fetching it, like in `foo.bars.all` in the template fetches data *from the database*. So all non-persistent changes are lost.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform

```
for bar in foo.bars.all():
   #This property 'allow_something' doesn't exist in model, I just need it in this situation
   bar.allow_something = True
```

`allow_something` only exists for as long you're in the forloop block, but the objects in the queryset haven't been updated, that's why it doesn't work in the template.

Assuming not everything is supposed to be true and the logic required isn't too hefty, you can easily check something in the template

```
{% for bar in foo.bars.all %}
    {% if bar.something == 'something' %}
        ...
     {% else %}
        ...
     {% endif %
{% endfor %}
```